# `transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbol` is not executing

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-3.1.0

I have a routine that expects AGP to produce `app/build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/debug` directory on `assembleDebug`. Also I have some aars with native code in my dependencies. It works pretty well on my local machine but doesn't work on my CI. I discovered that this folder is produced by task `transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug`. But on my CI it doesn't even have such task.

`Task with path 'transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug' not found in project ':app'`

Unfortunately I cannot tell what is wrong. At least not without AGP source code.

So the questing is: what triggers `transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbol` to execute during `assemble` or how do I force it?

I'm using AGP 3.1.3 and gradle wrapper 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found out that AGP will throw NDK-related tasks only if  NDK is configured (duh), i.e. `ndk.dir` is set in `local.properties` or `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`/`ANDROID_NDK` (I'm not sure which one is mandatory) environmental variable is set.

UPD: According to AGP source code it is `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`, at least at the moment.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/refs/heads/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/Sdk.groovy#205